# How to generate the multiple xml file using java. Like click on to submit button each time, it should create seperate xml file

Tags: java, xml

Example
when I click on the submit button, it should generate the xmlFile1.xml. Then again i click on to the submit button  it should generate the xmlFile2.xml.,,,xmlFine4,5,6.xml

Comment: What you have tried? Post your code. Btw are using swing or web app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check what files already exists in your Directory and create new name based on that.

If you want to list exisiting files you can use following method:

```
java.io.File.listFiles()
```

on your directory.

Comment: I used the this method. But I want create the multiple file.